# Azure Devops: how configure my pipeline script to trigger another pipeline with different repo?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have my own pipeline **p-A** with repository **r-A**, and pipeline **p-B** with another repo **r-B**.

I want to update the pipeline script for **p-A** only, to trigger the **p-B** actively, without any modification in **p-B**.

Below is the yaml pipeline script for **p-B**, which is already set up to run with schedule

```
pool:
  name: 'workflow_test_pool'

schedules:
   - cron: "0 19 * * *"
     displayName: run test every day at 8PM CET
     branches:
       include:
         - main
     always: true

trigger: none

jobs:
  - job:
    timeoutInMinutes: 30
    steps:
      - script: |
          python -m pytest tests/ -s
        displayName: 'Run the test'
```

below is the pipeline script **main.yaml** for **p-A**

```
pool:
  name: 'workflow_test_pool'

stages:
  #########################
  - template: pipeline2/p1.yaml


  ############################
  - template: pipeline2/p2.yaml
    parameters:
      dependsOn:
        - FirstPipeline
```

so the question is, how to trigger the pipeline **p-B** in **pipeline2/p2.yaml**(from **p-A**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create PowerShell script task as the last step of the pipeline to trigger pipeline p-B through REST API. You will have to maintain Personal Access Token, ideally as secret variable.

REST API call you will use:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Detailed step-by-step guide:
https://blog.geralexgr.com/cloud/trigger-azure-devops-build-pipelines-using-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps supports multiple repositories checkout, you can just reference resources function in your YAML script and call another repository to trigger from the pipeline.

YAML code :-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

workspace:

clean: all

  

resources:

repositories:

- repository: repo_a

type: git

name: InternalProjects/repo_a

trigger:

- main

- release

  

- repository: repo_b

type: git

name: InternalProjects/repo_b

trigger:

- main

steps:

- checkout: repo_a

- checkout: repo_b

  

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

I am running this pipeline from repo_a and the repo_a and repo_b both ran successfully like below:-

Output :-

[image]

You can directly run any task from pipeline with multiple repositories like below:-

```yaml
# Starter pipeline

# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

# https://aka.ms/yaml

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

workspace:

clean: all

  

resources:

repositories:

- repository: repo_a

type: git

name: InternalProjects/repo_a

trigger:

- main

- release

  

- repository: repo_b

type: git

name: InternalProjects/repo_b

trigger:

- main

steps:

- checkout: repo_a

  

- checkout: repo_b

- task: AzureCLI@2

inputs:

azureSubscription: 'Subscription-name(sub-id)'

scriptType: 'bash'

scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'

inlineScript: 'az resource list --location uksouth'
```

Output:-

[image]

**References :-**

[Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

[Trigger azure Devops pipeline from another repository - GeralexGR](https://blog.geralexgr.com/devops/trigger-azure-devops-pipeline-from-another-repository)

[Multiple Repositories in a Single Azure Pipeline - DEV Community ‍‍](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/multiple-repositories-in-a-single-azure-pipeline-2oe2)